# how to use a linked list defined in another class in python

Tags: python, linked-list

This is a  simple swap nodes in linked list code

```
__author__ = 'kingsley'

# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = None
    def add( self, data ) :
        node = ListNode( data )
        if self.head == None :
            self.head = node
        else :
            node.next = self.head
            node.next.prev = node
            self.head = node
def Print(self):
    temp = self.head
    while temp is not None:
        print(temp.val, end=' ')
        temp = temp.next


class Solution:
    # @param {ListNode} head
    # @return {ListNode}
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        if head == None or head.next == None:
            return head
        dummy = ListNode(0)
        dummy.next = head
        p = dummy
        while p.next and p.next.next:
            tmp = p.next.next
            p.next.next = tmp.next
            tmp.next = p.next
            p.next = tmp
            p = p.next.next
    def Print(self, head):
        tmp = self.head
        while tmp is not None:
            print(tmp.val)
            tmp = tmp.next


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = LinkedList(None)
    for i in range(1,11):
        list.add(i)
    list.Print();
    swap = Solution()
    swap.swapPairs(list.head);
    swap.Print(list.head);
```

The error is like this
AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute 'head'
what is the problem here
how can I use a linked list defined in another class

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Solution` class doesn't have *any* attributes, `head` or otherwise. And there's no obvious attributes it *should* have. (It's not really a class in any useful way; it's just a collection of functions written for no good reason as methods.)

If you want to access the `head` that you were passed as a parameter, just do that. Change this line:

```
tmp = self.head
```

… to this:

```
tmp = head
```

And now your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
self.head = head
```

in your `__init__` of `Solution` class.

Inside `Print` function, you try to make `tmp = self.head`, but you never defined self.head.

Or, you could make `tmp = head` instead.